# how to get variable value from javascript to jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

i have created dynamic rows(textboxes) in jsp by using javascript. After giving the values to those fields how can i retrieve the values into my result jsp page.

Comment: Any code would be great.

Comment: welcome to SO....before you go ahead just read once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Give a code example so we have a better idea of how your code looks now and what we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be overlooking on something. What is the exact requirement?

I doubt that is even possible because 
JavaScript executes on the client side after JSP page is already compiled and sent to the browser as response.

Answer (score 0):

1. While creating your rows in js assign a unique [name](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp) to each cell (something like `'text_[i]_[j]'` if you are using two loops the outer running on `i` and the inner running on `j`)
2. Submit the page
3. Use [request.getParameter("text_[i]_[j]")](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve the value.